# Wrongly displaying of checkbox component from Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

In simple form, checkbox from `Vuetify` displaying like raw text:
[image]

```
<v-form class="form-login" v-model="valid" ref="form" lazy-validation>
      <v-text-field label="Login"
                    v-model="username"
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    v-model="password"
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-checkbox
                  v-model="checkbox"
      ></v-checkbox>
</v-form>
```

If I use not the component, but own checkbox it works fine:

```
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="rememberMe"/>
```

Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: Looks like the "material icons" font isn't loaded. How are you loading the vuetify css?

Comment: What do You mean, how can I check this? I add `vuetify` dependencies to `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are not loading the vuetify css correctly. Simply adding the vuetify dependencies to `package.json` will not load the styles.

The easiest way to load the css ([as documented here](https://vuetifyjs.com/vuetify/quick-start)) would be to add this to the `<head>` section of your `index.html` file:

```
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
```